# Spring MVC managing multiple views with single controller

Tags: spring-mvc

Looking for an effective way to implement order management module. There are different order types (approximately about 15). Each order has a seperate view. But the actions performed on UI are same irrespective of order type. Below is the structure of my DTO

```
abstract class Order

abstract class SecurityOrder extends Order

abstract class TermDepositOrder extends Order
.....
.....
.....
```

I am trying to implement a single controller capable of managing all views. Something similar to the one below:

```
@Controller
public class OrderController<F extends Order> {

    public F validate(F order) {
    }

    public F insert(F order) {
    }
}
```

I am not sure how spring mvc would be able to map request parameters properly to the order instance as it doesn't know which order instance to instantiate.

Is it possible to achieve this with single controller or should I go with a controller for each order type and duplicate same code across all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do it by providing a custom Method Processor. Below is the sample code.

Custom Implementation:

```
public class OrderControllerArgumentResolver extends 
            ModelAttributeMethodProcessor { 

    public OrderControllerArgumentResolver() { 
            super(true); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter paramMethodParameter) { 
            //Resolve - custom annotation created to differentiate order parameter from others. 
            //This is to make sure this resolver is used only while resolving OrderDTO is used as method parameter 
            if (paramMethodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(Resolve.class) != null) { 
                    return true; 
            } 
            return false; 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected final Object createAttribute(String attributeName, 
                    MethodParameter parameter, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory, 
                    NativeWebRequest request) throws Exception { 
            //Instantiate appropriate order instance based on input. 
            return BeanUtils.instantiateClass(OrderTypeEnum.getDTOClass(request 
                            .getParameter("orderType"))); 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void bindRequestParameters(WebDataBinder binder, 
                    NativeWebRequest request) { 
            ServletRequest servletRequest = request 
                            .getNativeRequest(ServletRequest.class); 
            ServletRequestDataBinder servletBinder = (ServletRequestDataBinder) binder; 
            servletBinder.bind(servletRequest); 
    } 
}
```

Configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers> 
            <bean 
                    class="test.util.OrderControllerArgumentResolver" /> 
    </mvc:argument-resolvers> 
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Was able to achieve desired result with this approach. But not sure whether this approach cause any other problems. Please suggest.